# How should I get the AUC for the negative class?

Tags: scikit-learn

I am using [sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score.html#sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score) to compute the AUC of my binary classification model:

```
roc_auc_score(Y_test_binary, plc.predict_proba(X_test, y_true))
```

It returns 0.810477872581. Based on my understanding, it represents how well the model identifies the positive class.

However, I also want to know the other side: I would like to calculate the AUC for the negative class as well. How should I do it? Should I play with the "average" parameter?

========================================================

It seems that "average=None" can "return the scores for each class" according to the documentation. But it still only returns one value:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score
>>> y_true = np.array([0, 0, 1, 1])
>>> y_scores = np.array([0.1, 0.4, 0.35, 0.8])
>>> roc_auc_score(y_true, y_scores, average=None)
0.75
```

I expect one number for class 1 and one number for class 0.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that it makes sense to speak of AUC for the negative class in a binary classification problem. I would say it's just (1 - AUC score) computed with the positive class.

To convince your-self let's reuse your example:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score
>>> y_true = np.array([0, 0, 1, 1])
>>> y_scores = np.array([0.1, 0.4, 0.35, 0.8])
>>> roc_auc_score(y_true, y_scores)
0.75
```

You can swithc the labels of y_true and get 0.25:

```
>>> (y_true == 0).astype(np.int32)
array([1, 1, 0, 0], dtype=int32)

>>> roc_auc_score(y_true == 0, y_scores)
0.25
```

The `average` parameter is only used for multi-class problems.

Comment: I actually had the same thought. But considering this example: y_true = np.array([0, 0, 1, 1]), y_scores = np.array([0.1, 0.1, 0.9, 0.9]). In this case, the calssifier can distinguish both classes very well. The AUC for class1 is 1 while the AUC for class0 is 0. It seems that both should be 1.